# How to assign a shortcut key to show all windows in Compiz

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.10, compiz

It should be pretty easy, but I couldn't find the option. With Ubuntu tweak (Compiz settings -> Edge preferences) I configured the lower right border of the screen to show all windows.

I'd like to have a shortcut key that does exactly that and I'd also like it to be the default behaviour of the alt-tab key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oops, I've just found it

it's the "scale" compiz plugin

Comment: sure alex, it's just I haven't been here for a long time...